# Picasso IOException, Invalid marker: ef

Tags: java, android, image, picasso, android-glide

I download an Image for later offline use

the file path : `/storage/emulated/0/3a3d95e7b3e84cfb795e4a31bbdf98d1.jpg`

I got this exception while passing it to picasso :

```
java.io.IOException: Invalid marker: ef
             at android.media.ExifInterface.getJpegAttributes(ExifInterface.java:1635)
             at android.media.ExifInterface.loadAttributes(ExifInterface.java:1344)
             at android.media.ExifInterface.<init>(ExifInterface.java:1062)
             at com.squareup.picasso.FileRequestHandler.getFileExifRotation(FileRequestHandler.java:46)
             ....
```

This exception occurs even when I try to load a png file (which does not have exif). The method I use to store the images :

```
public static String okDownloadToFileSync(final String link, final String fileName, final boolean temp, DownloadStatusManager statusManager, ErrorDisplayerInterface errorDisplayerInterface) {

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url(link)
        .build();

    if (statusManager != null) {
        statusManager.add(Hash.md5(link));
    }

    OkHttpClient client = Api.getInstance().getOkHttpClient();
    OutputStream output = null;
    InputStream input = null;
    String fileFullName = null;

    try {

        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();


        final String contentType = response.header("Content-Type");

        final String ext = contentTypeMap.get(contentType);
        Log.i(TAG, link + "\n --> contentType = " + contentType + "\n --> ext = " + ext);

        if (ext == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "-----------\next is null, seems like there is a problem with that url : \n         " + link + "\n----------");
            return null;
        } else if (ext.equals("json")) {
            Log.e(TAG, "-----------\ndownloadable file seems to be a json, seems like there is a problem with that url : \n         " + link + "\n----------");
            return null;
        }

        //Check if file already exists
        if (!temp && fileName != null) {
            File test = new File(STORAGE_PATH + fileName + "." + ext);
            if (test.exists()) {
                Log.i(TAG, "File exists ! : " + test.getPath());
                return STORAGE_PATH + fileName + "." + ext;
            }
        }

        // expect HTTP 200 OK, so we don't mistakenly save error report
        // instead of the file
        if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
            Log.e(TAG, "dwnToFileSync bug : connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK");
            return null;
        }

        ResponseBody responseBody = response.body();
        if (statusManager != null) {
            statusManager.add(Hash.md5(link), responseBody.contentLength());
        }

        input = responseBody.byteStream();

        if (temp) {
            //If there is a pb with pdf, add '.pdf' as suffix
            File file = File.createTempFile(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), ext, M360Application.getContext().getCacheDir());
            fileFullName = file.getPath();
            output = new FileOutputStream(file);
        } else {
            File file = new File(STORAGE_PATH + fileName + "." + ext);
            fileFullName = file.getPath();
            Log.i(TAG, "File full name : " + fileFullName);
            output = new FileOutputStream(file);
        }

        Log.i(TAG, fileFullName);

        byte data[] = new byte[4096];
        long total = 0;
        int count;
        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
            output.write(data, 0, count);
            total++;
        }


        return fileFullName;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        errorDisplayerInterface.popError(null, e);
    } finally {
        if (statusManager != null) {
            statusManager.finish(Hash.md5(link));
        }
        try {
            if (output != null)
                output.close();
            if (input != null)
                input.close();
        } catch (IOException ignored) {
            ignored.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    return null;
}
```

note that this method is also used to download files of all types which are correctly read by their respectives player.

Do you know where this "ef" could come from ?

if I try with `iv.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getPath()));` I just have this message :

```
 skia: --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
```

I tried glide to see if i had a clearer error message :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000
at android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(Native Method)
at android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(MediaMetadataRetriever.java: 136)
at com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.VideoBitmapDecoder.decode(VideoBitmapDecoder.java: 46)
at com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.FileDescriptorBitmapDecoder.decode(FileDescriptorBitmapDecoder.java: 45)
at com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.FileDescriptorBitmapDecoder.decode(FileDescriptorBitmapDecoder.java: 19)
at com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.ImageVideoBitmapDecoder.decode(ImageVideoBitmapDecoder.java: 50)
at com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.ImageVideoBitmapDecoder.decode(ImageVideoBitmapDecoder.java: 20)
at com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.gifbitmap.GifBitmapWrapperResourceDecoder.decodeBitmapWrapper(GifBitmapWrapperResourceDecoder.java: 121)
at com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.gifbitmap.GifBitmapWrapperResourceDecoder.decodeStream(GifBitmapWrapperResourceDecoder.java: 94)
at com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.gifbitmap.GifBitmapWrapperResourceDecoder.decode(GifBitmapWrapperResourceDecoder.java: 71)
at com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.gifbitmap.GifBitmapWrapperResourceDecoder.decode(GifBitmapWrapperResourceDecoder.java: 61)
at com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.gifbitmap.GifBitmapWrapperResourceDecoder.decode(GifBitmapWrapperResourceDecoder.java: 22)
at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.decodeFromSourceData(DecodeJob.java: 190)
at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.decodeSource(DecodeJob.java: 177)
at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.decodeFromSource(DecodeJob.java: 128)
at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.EngineRunnable.decodeFromSource(EngineRunnable.java: 122)
at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.EngineRunnable.decode(EngineRunnable.java: 101)
at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.EngineRunnable.run(EngineRunnable.java: 58)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java: 423)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java: 237)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java: 1113)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java: 588)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java: 818)
at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.executor.FifoPriorityThreadPoolExecutor$DefaultThreadFactory$1.run(FifoPriorityThreadPoolExecutor.java: 118)
```

Thanks !